# Coroutine RoomDB NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting a `NullPointerException` and `invokeSuspend` error when trying to get data from a Room DAO using a Kotlin coroutine. Do I need to do something special in order to use room and coroutines work together? The data that I'm querying definitely exists in the database.

**The Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
Process: com.school, PID: 29799
java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.school.Repository$fetchStudentInfo$1.invokeSuspend(Repository.kt:25)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

**The Presenter**

```
class Presenter(val view: View, val repository: Repository) {
    fun fetchStudentInfo() {
        repository.fetchStudentInfo(studentId)
    }
    fun displayStudentInfo(isGraduated: Boolean) {
        view.displayStudentInfo(isGraduated)
    }
}
```

**The Repository**

```
class Repository(val roomdb: RoomDB, val presenter: Presenter) {
    fun fetchStudentInfo(studentId: Long) {
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            val deferred = async { roomdb.studentDao().findById(studentId) }
            presenter.displayStudentInfo(deferred.await())
        }
    }
}
```

**The DAO**

```
@Dao
interface StudentDao {
    @Query("SELECT isGraduated FROM studentdata WHERE id = (:id)")
    suspend fun findById(id: String): Boolean
}
```

Comment: I suspect that if does not exist in DB and it returns null, treat it as a `Boolean?` and check for a true value

Comment: @Amin Nope the data definitely exists in the db

Comment: I also suspect that `id = (:id)` may not be a valid sql syntax, can you try `id = :id` or `id = ':id'`